# Rename 2 tables within the same stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, rename, dynamic-sql

I have written a stored procedure to rename a table to old and rename the temp table current in the same procedure so that users don't see an empty table while the temp table is loading.  Each execute immediate does rename both tables, however I get an error saying sql command not properly executed.  If I commit each of the executes, the procedure runs without issue.  Am i getting this error because I cannot rename one procedure to another one in the same procedure or is there something else I am missing?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my program:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RENAME_TABLE
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      ('ALTER TABLE CURRENT_TABLE RENAME TO CURRENT_TABLE_OLD');

   --rename current table to old
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('rename current to old');
   COMMIT;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      ('ALTER TABLE CURRENT_TABLE_TMP RENAME TO CURRENT_TABLE');

   --rename tmp table to current
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('rename tmp to current');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- There was a problem somewhere.  Display the error code.
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Exception raised during RENAME_TABLE'
         || TO_CHAR (SQLCODE)
         || ' - '
         || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END;
/
```

Comment: I dont see any issues. Do you get issue when you execute the proc? post that code too

Comment: Remove the `EXCEPTION` block and re-run.  It will tell you the exact error and the line number it happened on.  Never add exception handling unless it does more than the default exception handling behavior.

Comment: looks like it might have been user error on this one.  Thanks all!

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: I think you should do it on two separate procedure this may because the procedure run in same batch.